# Tinymce auto detect embed link like wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, iframe, tinymce

How to make tinymce plugin auto detect social embed link and make embed code automatically just like WordPress Text Editor.

need to save only url in a database, not whole iframe code while saving just like Wordpress.

Currently, I am embedding through source code. and it is really difficult and when I use a plugin like Grammarly it automatically removes iframe code.

Comment: Try to paste the code in "Code" view rather than "Visual" editor

Comment: Recently I am doing same, but the problem is that whenever start to edit in the grammerly app, then its automatically remove all the iframe code from the text editor.